# Vim YouCompleteMe clang-completer complains it can not find 'omp.h' file where Eigen (C++ library) calls for it

Tags: clang, openmp, eigen, youcompleteme

I am using Vim's YouCompleteMe C semantic completer installed with the --clang-completer flag. It complains that it can not find the 'omp.h' file used in the Eigen/Core library file. Error message is as follows:

```
In included file: 'omp.h' file not found  /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:247:10: note: error occurred here [pp_file_not_found]
```

The code compiles and runs perfect, so that's why I know it is not a real issue and something wrong with YouCompleteMe. I have tried using both clang and clangd, it does not matter, same issue.

If I simply remove the `-fopenmp` from the compile_command.json file, it fixes the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The pre-built clangs from llvm.org don't include openmp. YCM includes a copy of the clang resource dir from the pre-built llvm.org packages, therefore 'omp.h' (which is part of the resource dir) is not found.

If you need to use openmp, then i suggest you set `g:ycm_clangd_binary_path` to point to a clangd that is installed alongside your llvm toolchain containing openmp.